# PHPexcel CONCATENATE makes blank column

Tags: php

i have this commands, other columns has its data, but I2 is empty, no function, nothing
i think im donig something wrong, but dont know what.
thanks

in I2 is this data "2012/10"

```
$foo->mergeCells("B$rowCounter:E$rowCounter");
$foo->setCellValue("B$rowCounter", "Lukáš Doubek")
    ->setCellValue("F$rowCounter", "IČ: 77889977")
    ->setCellValue("H$rowCounter", "Variabilní symbol")
    ->setCellValue("I$rowCounter", '=CONCATENATE("LEFT(I2;4)","RIGHT(I2;2)")');
$rowCounter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is an excel command, not a php one, I believe this line is incorrect :

```
->setCellValue("I$rowCounter", '=CONCATENATE("LEFT(I2;4)","RIGHT(I2;2)")');
```

Shouldn't it, instead, be like this?

```
->setCellValue("I$rowCounter", '=CONCATENATE("LEFT(I2,4)","RIGHT(I2,2)")');
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this help! 
the right command is 

    ->setCellValue("I$rowCounter", "=CONCATENATE(LEFT(I2,4),RIGHT(I2,2))");

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of assistance.